# How are selectors implemented internally?

Tags: java, nio

I've just started exploring java NIO, non-blocking IO. 
I'm interested to know the fundamentals behind the implementation. How is communication between Java selector and physical socket is established? Is there a operating system level thread that polls underlying resource continuously? And is there any java thread per selector continously polling to receive these events? Can someone of you kindly point me to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better first give you a picture(take from other guy's blog)
 
[image: old IO and NIO]
<sub>(source: [csdn.net](http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/haoel/15190/o_java.nio.00.jpg))</sub>

Also some information get from that blog,

1. For select implementation,it depends on OS. For epoll/select in *nix ENV, you can get more information from 《Unix network programming》
2. And for notify/wakeup the select, the JVM also use different implementation, like TCP/IP on windows, pipes on *nix.

Comment: could you please put a reference link to the blog?

Answer (score 7):

No, the point of `select` is that you *don't* have to waste cycles polling when nothing is happening. Every OS implements this capability in some way or other (usually through hardware interrupts) and makes it available to user-space programs through the `select()` system call. The connection to the Java language is that the JVM now contains code that will call the OS's `select` for you if you use the right NIO classes and methods. But this required changes to the JVM code itself, it isn't something that you could have done purely within Java before NIO.

Comment: Kilan, Thanks for quick response. However, the following point elludes my understanding >> and makes it available to user-space programs through the select() system call <<. When is JVM going to call select() method? Does it poll? If that is the case a thread per selector should exist? Correct?

Comment: No, when you use NIO select, as in this example (www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/NbClient.html), the JVM calls `select` at the point where it interprets the bytecode for the NIO `select`. This means that the calling thread is suspended until an answer is available - there isn't any new thread allocated.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is not specified in the documentation, I'd assume that (strictly speaking) this is implementation dependent.

However in *NIX and Windows the implementation typically relies directly on the `select` system call. This system call is not implemented by spawning multiple threads.

Comment: aioobe, Even if we assume that OS is using some kind of hardware interrupts and setting, unsetting flags to signify the events, shouldn't there be java thread that continously monitors these flags and throw the events?

Comment: Well, select is a blocking call right? The thread that perform the select will end up in a select-system-call that does not return until interrupted, so no, no java thread that "continously monitors the flags".

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the operation system used.  On Linux the current implementation use's the kernel's [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) mechanism.

Typically the underlying kernel network system is filling or draining buffers for the socket, probably on it's IRQ handling threads.  So what you are waiting for is the kernel to tell you that a buffer is ready to be filled (writing) or read to be draining (reading).

Comment: And how does Java get interrupted by epoll's event? And also how does Java interupt your own code to notify tje event was received?